# AccessibilityService works at random?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm working on app which needs to know when notification arrives. I'm using accessibilityservice for this task.

When I give permission to my custom accessibilityservice (going to Accessibility-> MyApp ->ON), onServiceConnected is called and everything works fine for some time. My app receives events..

But after some time (like hour or so), my app stops getting notified about new notifications. I must disable AccesibilityService and enable it again in order to work.

Of course this is not acceptable since user will not do that everytime..

Below is my code.

```
  @Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();


    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.packageNames = null;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;
    setServiceInfo(info);

}
```

And Manifest.

```
 <!-- Accesibility Service Declaration below -->

    <service android:name="services.MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />

        </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.accessibilityservice" android:resource="@xml/service_request" />

    </service>
```

For testing purposes I was using HTC One M7 running on KitKat Android OS. So Why my app stops receiving notifications after some time? Any help would be REALLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the suggested usage is now to use a NotificationListener instead of AccessibilityService to detect notifications

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html